# How get lowerest chrono unit from date format?

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time

Look at examples:

```
yyyy-MM-dd -> java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS
yyyy-MM-dd HH -> java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.HOURS
yyyy;HH;ss -> java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS
yyyy;dd;MM -> java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS
```

is there API to grab lowerest chrono unit from date time string format?

Comment: What's the source? A `String`? Is the pattern known before?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to parse a predetermined date and check which units have values. I've written a quick example below which outputs:

> yyyy-MM-dd    Days
>   yyyy-MM-dd HH Hours
>   yyyy;HH;ss    Seconds
>   yyyy;dd;MM ss n   Nanos

Notes:

- it relies on the fact that the units are in ascending order within the ChronoField enum.
- it will work for built-in units (year, month, day, second, nanos) but may not give the result you want for other fields such as week-based fields or milli/microseconds fields for example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] formats = { "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MM-dd HH", "yyyy;HH;ss", "yyyy;dd;MM ss n" };
    LocalDateTime test = LocalDateTime.of(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    for (String f : formats) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(f);
        TemporalAccessor accessor = format.parse(test.format(format));
        for (ChronoField unit : ChronoField.values()) {
            if (testUnit(accessor, unit)) {
                System.out.println(f + " " + unit.getBaseUnit());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean testUnit(TemporalAccessor accessor, ChronoField unit) {
    return accessor.isSupported(unit) && accessor.getLong(unit) == 1;
}
```

Comment: I was writing an answer, but this one is better, brilliant. For testing a unit `accessor.isSupported(unit) && accessor.getLong(unit) == 1` would probably work and not throw any exception.

Comment: You need `getLong()` though, since you may sometimes get a value that overflows an `int`, which would lead to an exception. So I have edited.